# portquiz.net dlp test with python

Tags: python-3.x, networking

I am trying to get a response from portquiz.net when probing port 80.  For example, if we do this:

```
curl portquiz.net:80
```

we get the response:

```
Port 80 test successful!
```

Here is the python code:

```
import socket

server = "portquiz.net"
port = 80

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((server, port))
    response = s.recv(1024)
print(repr(response))
```

With this code I get no response, the script just seems to hang.
Is this an issue with my code or is it something to do with portquiz's server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fingers, that is an HTTP server, so you need to make a GET request to it. As soon as you connect it is waiting for you to send data, that is why it hangs.

You can do this more easily with an HTTP library, however, if you want to use `socket` here is the code, with example run:

```
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/stackoverflow/portquiz.net$ cat test.py

import socket

server = "portquiz.net"
port = 80

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((server, port))
    # Send HTTP GET request to / 
    s.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: {}\r\n\r\n'.format(server).encode())
    response = s.recv(1024)
print(repr(response))
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/stackoverflow/portquiz.net$ python test.py
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 21 Jul 2019 22:25:32 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Length: 2747\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Outgoing Port Tester</title>\n<style type="text/css">\nbody {\n\tfont-family: sans-serif;\n\tfont-size: 0.9em;\n}\n</style>\n\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<h1>Outgoing port tester</h1>\n\nThis server listens on all TCP ports, allowing you to test any outbound TCP port.\n\n<p>\nYou have reached this page on port <b>80</b>.<br/>\n</p>\n\nYour network allows you to use this port.\n(Assuming that your network is not doing advanced traffic filtering.)\n\n<p>\nNetwork service: http<br/>\nYour outgoing IP: 207.135.66.186</p>\n\n<h2>Test a port using a command</h2>\n\n<pre>\n$ telnet portquiz.net 80 \nTrying ...\nConnected to portquiz.net.\nEscape character is \'^]\'.\n</pre>\n<pre>\n$ nc -v portquiz.net 80 \nConnection to portquiz.net 80 port [tcp/daytime] succeeded!\n</pre>\n<pre>\n$ curl portquiz.net:80 \nPort 80 test successful!\nYour IP: 207.135.66.186</pre>\n<pre>\n$ wget -q'
```

Further thoughts on this, it looks like the sight might be looking for a CURL header when to determine which version - either HTML, or TEXT - that it sends. It may behoove you to specify the same header after the "HOST: " header that CURL does so the response is easier to parse.

For the example of it with a curl header, and how I figured out what to put there:

```
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/stackoverflow/portquiz.net$ curl portquiz.net:80 -vvvv
* Rebuilt URL to: portquiz.net:80/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.47.209.216...
* Connected to portquiz.net (52.47.209.216) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: portquiz.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2019 22:34:36 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 49
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
Port 80 test successful!
Your IP: 207.135.66.186
* Connection #0 to host portquiz.net left intact
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/stackoverflow/portquiz.net$ cat test.py

import socket

server = "portquiz.net"
port = 80

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((server, port))
    get_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: {}\r\n" \
                  "User-Agent: curl/7.35.0\r\n\r\n".format(server)
    s.send(get_request.encode())
    response = s.recv(1024)
print(repr(response))

(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/stackoverflow/portquiz.net$ python test.py
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 21 Jul 2019 22:34:47 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)\r\nContent-Length: 49\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nPort 80 test successful!\nYour IP: 207.135.66.186\n'
```

Comment: i changed the port to 20 and it hangs as before.  Would it be better to use a library to do curl commands instead of using socket?